# Scala Slick - Type mismatch issue

Tags: scala, slick

For typical snippet for Slick (3.3.2) for Scala (2.13) (Snippet copied from "Essential Slick" by Richard Dallaway and Jonathan Ferguson):

```
case class User(id: Long, name: String)

class UserTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "user") {
  def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def name = column[String]("name")
  def * = (id, name).mapTo[User]
}
```

I've got a bit strange-looking error:

```
Error: type mismatch 
found   : ((Long, String)) => User
required: ((Long, String)) => User
def * = (id, name).mapTo[User]
```

Kind regards
Marcin

Comment: Irreproducible https://scastie.scala-lang.org/dgUmDoJ6SFuy3gqFyeroUg

Comment: How do you build your project? Do `clean compile`.

Comment: IntelliJ worksheet.

Comment: There should be some import like `import slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile.api._`. Write  your imports and build file (if there is any, e.g. `build.sbt`).

Comment: `'import oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
import java.sql.{Date, DriverManager}

import slick.lifted._
import slick.basic.DatabaseConfig
import slick.driver
import slick.jdbc.OracleProfile.api._
import slick.jdbc.OracleProfile` `val d = new OracleDriver
val a = Database.forDriver(d,url,username,password)
`

Comment: Try to create a new project https://developer.lightbend.com/start/?group=slick&project=hello-slick-3.1

Comment: Many thanks for the hint! I am new to Slick and to Scala :). I have Sbt 0.13.7  installed. But Sbt still wants to download sbt 0.13.7 from non-existing paths. There are jars in similar paths with version 0.9.x and higher. I was downloading libraries manually. What should I do to have sbt running and the to preserve consistency what project is being developed in IntelliJ ?

Comment: 0.13.7 is very old sbt https://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html (I'm using 1.3.8) Read https://docs.scala-lang.org/getting-started/ Install sbt and create IntelliJ project: File -> New -> Project -> Scala -> sbt -> Next

Comment: I tried to reinstall recent but different versions of  sbt using *.msi (I need it installed on Windows). They seem to star correctly (downloading some libraries), but all versions stop at some time trying to get sbt 0.13.7)

Comment: Sorry I don't use windows https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Installing-sbt-on-Windows.html https://medium.com/@bbenz/installing-and-running-sbt-on-windows-10-d4f8e7ea7223